# Replacing non consecutive pages from one (InDesign exported) pdf file to another

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

From single document in InDesign I export 2 pdf files.

First pdf file contains all pages as grayscale, second pdf document contains only colour pages. Color pages pdf document carries information about page numbers.

How can I automatically replace relevant grayscale pages in first PDF document with respective colour pages from second PDF document?

**Example:**

- 1st exported PDF document has 100 grayscale pages.
- 2nd PDF document has color pages i.e.: 5,8,52,68,90.

I want to put these color pages from second PDF document into the first PDF document at once, by replacing the respective grayscale pages in it.

Comment: Do you have only 5 pages to replace?

Comment: 5 pages is a bit problematic for the printer, usulally you add pages at a multiple of 4 since each separate page adds reader pages worth of paper.

Comment: @joojaa It is just an example, but not his is not a point. First I have to prepare document in one-production (an this topic is about it) and in the end I make the 4-up production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to everyone who tried to find solution of my problem. Special thanks to @13ruce advice I found very nice and simple solution.

I use PDF Toolkit server and its feature of combining two files into the third one.

The general PDFTK string is:

```
pdftk K=black.pdf C=color.pdf cat K1-2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 K11 K12 output out.pdf
```

In this example the output.pdf will contain pages 1-2 from black.pdf, pages 3-10 from color.pdf and again pages 11-12 from black.pdf.

The only time consuming thing can be writing this string, especially, when the color pages are randomly distributed over the whole range of pages. That is why I programmed a simple utility in MS Excel, using VBA macro, that automatically creates this string.
You can [download it](http://www.equilibria.sk/upload/nemazat_Lu/PDFTK_StringCreator_v1.0.zip) free.

It looks like this:

[image]

Here are some instructions:

After opening xlsm file, macros need to be allowed.
Insert Total pages in document (cell B1).
Define which pages will be replaced by color ones (cell B2).
The last defined color page must be lower or equal the total pages.
Color pages must be comma separated, without space. In defining the page range dashes are not allowed in this version.
Press Create PDTK String and the PDFTK String will be written into cell B4.

If you have PDFTK server installed, you can use Total Commander to run PDFTK string. Just open it in the subfolder when your processed files are and insert PDFTK string into Command window of Total Commander. See the next picture.

black.pdf document contains all the document pages as black (grayscale), 
color.pdf document contains the same pages as color, 
out.pdf document contains all the black pages but pages defined in cell B2 are replaced by color ones.

I hope it will be helpful for someone. Feel free to give me ideas for improvements.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way for InDesign to manage this task unless you break each section into its own file and assemble it as an InDesign book (maybe?). That's probably more of a hassle than you want to deal with. However, PDFTK (PDF Toolkit) is a free tool that has (among other things) a combine function that will allow you to accomplish this via traditional command line, their more friendly command line tool or a batch file. You will place both color and BW PDF's in the same folder, run the command, and it will output the combined PDF per your pre-determined specifications.

Comment: Thanks for a tip, in another words I need to update/replace pages in BW pdf document with all the pages from color document. Is there an update command for pdftk server command line?

Comment: There is no "update" per se, but what you want can be achieved with PDFTK using the same commands used to create the original combined PDF. You simply drop the newly revised files into the working folder and run the command again. It's unnecessary to replace bad pages when it's so easy to completely rebuild from updated source files.

Comment: For example, if you have edited some of the bw pages, just export a new bw pdf and replace the old one (being sure the keep file names and page counts the same). Run the command again and PDFTK will output a new combined pdf containing the updated content.

Comment: I am not sure who of us does not understand so I will give an example again. We are printing books on color digital printing machines. The problem is, that the printing machine price for color page is about 3x more expansive than bw so I want to make sure that bw pages in printed file are REALLY bw. So when I want to get the printing pdf file from InDesign I do it the following way. I export all the pages of the book as b/w with InDesign export setting with bw profile (this is the 1st file with all the pages bw).

Comment: Then I export only color pages from the same InDesign file (this is the 2nd file with color pages, here are usually only several pages). Now comes the point. So far I had to manually drag and drop color pages, page by page, from 2nd file to 1st file, replacing respective bw pages by color ones. Sometimes it takes a time and you have to be careful not to make mistake. That's why I am looking for the solution how to replace the pages automatically. Acrobat allows to replace just the group of consecutive pages.

Comment: Pages in color pdf file have their numbers not from 1 to n, but real numbers as they appear in the InDesign document. How can I then update (in this case = replace or merge with replacing) the bw pdf file so that it would contain the same number of pages as it had, but relevant bw pages would be replaced by color ones?

Comment: Yes, I follow you. We have the exact same situation with some of our jobs, which are mostly bw with interspersed color pages. I honestly don't see what the confusion is, so it must be that my explanation is insufficient. I'll try to explain more clearly:

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, suppose your desired pdf were ten pages long, and pages 2 and 8 are color, with the rest black and white. The PDFTK command to assemble the mixed file would be something like:
pdftk A=bw.pdf B=color.pdf cat A1 B2 A3-7 B8 A9-10 output combined.pdf
Where it takes page 1 from your complete bw.pdf, page 2 from your complete color.pdf, ect., then output the result as combined.pdf.
Then, if any revisions are made to the InDesign document, you simply need to export two more complete bw and color pdfs and re-run the command. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Essentially, it takes whichever pages you want from any number of pdfs and outputs them as a new pdf assembled in any order you like. If that doesn't solve your problem, then I don't know what would. I wish you the very best of luck!

Comment: Yes, now it is absolutely clear, but I am not sure if this way is faster than drag-and-drop in Acrobat because in this case you have to create the combination of A's and B's first. It is easy with 10 pages, but may be time-consuming with 300. But it is definitely worth if you need to update it several times after changes in InDesign. My challenge now is to make an Excel or Access VBA script to make this combination string. Input will be color page numbers and the total page number, output will be the A..B.. combination. Thanks a lot for your time and effort. I appreciate it.

Comment: I will post a comment when the script will be ready, but it can take some time.

Comment: The initial set up may not be much faster, true. However, once it is set up, if any changes are made, it's a simple matter of re-running the original script to produce an updated production file. Furthermore, for future jobs with different configurations, it takes me much less time to modify the script than it would to drag/drop via Acrobat. There will always be a trade-off, of course. For very small documents, or some with only one color section, the Acrobat method may be best.

Comment: @Lubos Why don't you simply re-import your grayscale pictures in the grayscale version, and globally change the colors of the text using the swatches? I would do this for 3-5-100-10000pages, it's still the best way. You can simply MOVE the color pictures somewhere else and relink the images with grayscale version that you put in the links folder (keep same name files.) Otherwise copy-paste your 5 InDesign pages. Or output a grayscale PDF but frankly that's not the best way.

Comment: @go-me There are often complicating factors with this kind of project that go beyond simply using grayscale images. Using colors in type styles and running background elements would be ponderous to manage if there had to be separate bw and color versions employed where necessary. Then there are things like registration marks and color bars that always print color. It's far easier for a large document to export two PDFs; one color, one bw and recombine a mixed pdf to ensure that only color pages get charged for color clicks on the output device.

Comment: Two separate InDesign files?

Comment: @13ruce, as I wrote in previous comment I can make the simple VBA script in Excel or Access, but Excel is more common, that makes initial setup very easy. You just write the comma delimited numbers of color pages into certain cell, press the button "Run" and the output will be string with A's and B's to put into pdftk command. I have already something similar to set up, what pages will be printed on color printer as inserts for BW printer and set up the number of color inserts after relevant BW pages. It is very helpful.

Comment: Also Enfocus Pitstop has the functionality to transfer the color pdf page to grayscale, but my experience is, that the only 100% way is export it as grayscale from InDesign. As 13ruce wrote, there may often be the elements on the pdf page that make color printer count page as color.

Comment: If there is a gray fill in every page of InDesign (for example in header), and you export separately Color and BW pages into pdf, after combining these documents and replacing pages, the headers colors on color pages are not the same as on BW pages. You have to change it, but it can be easily done with Pitstop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in **Acrobat Pro**. You can do this manually trough the GUI but it might get involved so you can just type this in the JavaScript console

1. Open the document you want to manipulate.
2. Open the JavaScript console, you can find it in the debugger.
3. In console type:

   ```
   this.insertPages({ nPage: 4 ,cPath:"x:\\path\\color.pdf", nStart: 0});
   this.insertPages({ nPage: 7 ,cPath:"x:\\path\\color.pdf", nStart: 1});
   this.insertPages({ nPage: 51 ,cPath:"x:\\path\\color.pdf", nStart: 2});
   this.insertPages({ nPage: 67 ,cPath:"x:\\path\\color.pdf", nStart: 3});
   this.insertPages({ nPage: 89 ,cPath:"x:\\path\\color.pdf", nStart: 4});
   ```
4. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>to execure
5. Save. Your done.

You can also do this from command line. Or togh the Acrobat API.

#### Edit

For a bit better usability use:

```
var pages = [0,2];
for (var i = 0; i < pages.length;i++){
    var page = pages[i];
    var pagebefore = page-1;
    this.deletePages({nStart: page});
    this.insertPages({ 
         nPage: pagebefore,
         cPath:"x:\\path\\color.pdf",
         nStart: i // or use `page` if you have exact same document
    });
}
```

Comment: Good to know. Does that also delete the bw analogs?

Comment: @13ruce no that would be `this.deletePages`. I was a bit distracted by other things when i wrote this

Comment: @13ruce Added a slightly more usable script

Answer (score 1):

**1. Color Swatches**

If it was my project, I would update my color swatches to grayscale and the style will be updated as well. Or vice versa.

Of course, it's something easier to do if you plan from the start that you'll use 2 versions; this way you add color swatches for your grayscale 60% and name them this way, and then replace that recipe with the color one you want. Or vice versa. I hope I make sense.

**2. Pictures: Move them**

If you have a lot of pictures to replace, you can always move the color pictures somewhere else and put the grayscale in the linked folder, using the same names.

Then you go in the Links panel and simply relink one image that is now in the linked folder, and it will link back all the others as well from the same folder with the same name... They will get updated in InDesign, at the same exact size and position.

It's really the fastest way to update everything. If you have a lot of pictures to update, I don't know exactly if it works for InDesign but in Quark, I even put my mouse on the numeral keypad *Enter Key* and its weight presses the "ok" button to update, so I don't even need to click anything if there's a lot of images to update :D (I know it's ultra lazy, but admit it, it's clever!)

**3. 2x Documents**

Personally, I prefer to prepare 2 documents for this; one grayscale and one in color. If there's lot of changes, I simply use the grayscale version as main one and then do a duplicate in color with the tricks above. My priority will always be on the version that goes on press and I guess it's the grayscale one for you.

**4. Why not use the "insert" command in Acrobat Pro**

You can still do what I mentioned above, export your 5 pages from InDesign and then use the "insert" command in Acrobat Pro to replace the grayscale pages with the color ones. Or Vice Versa.

That seems faster than trying to find "automatic" solutions and at least you can verify manually if you replaced the right pages.

---

Also:

- Printers usually ignore registration marks when there's obviously
  only these using CMY, just so you know. You simply need to mention it's a one color job and you'll be fine. When they "rip" your work, they don't send 4 separations for no reasons, plates are not free. And real proofs are done with the exact color separations too.
- And there's no color separation on digital printing, it's like
  printing grayscale on your home inkjet.
- InDesign colorbars are decorative to printers as well, they use their
  own.
- **With Acrobat Pro you can always flatten all this to
  grayscale in Preflight if you want to be certain there's no CMY left
  and it can even convert your whole PDF to grayscale, if that can
  help.** I still suggest you do your color changes in InDesign and adjust your grayscale pictures in Photoshop for better results.
- One last thing, if that project is meant to be printed, know that you
  could always provide your 5 color pages as a separate document and
  mention to your printer where they go. As Jooja mentioned, these will
  be printed separately anyway and need to be 'imposed'. In fact the
  printer himself will isolate them to print them separately...! So
  maybe you could ask the printer if you can simply provide a 5 pages
  PDF with your color pages and add a note on the grayscale pages in
  the PDF to mention the color page goes there.

Comment: Thanks for your long answer. Yes, I can insert or replace pages with "insert" command, but only series of consecutive pages. Also Acrobat Pro Preflight allows me to change page content into gray, but again only series of consecutive pages or current page. My problem is, better said was, that the pages I need to replace are far not consecutive, but random and sometimes there are quite a lot of them. I have found solution thanks to 13ruce advise to use PDF Toolkit and combine two files into the third one.

Comment: The only bad thing on it is, that you need to write PDFTK string defining  how to combine the pages in files. I made a simple Excel VBA macro based file which I will try to post in a while.

Answer (score -1):

Use Adobe Acrobat 3D to replace pages in pdf file.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and explain a bit more how Acrobat 3D can fix that issue?