# Data merge for PDF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, pdf, actions, python

Lets say I have 100 PDFs in one folder1 (filename: 1, 2,3,4..) and another 100 PDF in another folder2 (Filename: 1,2,3,4...). Now I want to combine PDF1 in folder1 with PDF1 in folder2 and so on till pdf100 from folder1 is combined with pdf100 in folder2.

The PDF in folder 1 shoudl be placed in the first page of the pdf1 in folder2. (this applies for all the pdf)

How can this be implemented? Can we use data merge? Will Photoshop be useful or indesign or acrobat reader?

Comment: I'm thinking that I would make an indesign script that combines the pdf files it to single document in order, export that to pdf and then use the split feature in Acrobat to split the pdf every 2 pages. (It could be done straight from indesign, but I feel this would be simpler).

Comment: HI joonas, thanks for the reply..the problem is, folder1 is just a one page jpeg image in pdf format and folder2 has 100 pdf's with different page numbers...If you think you have a simpler method to combine..please let me know..the main idea is to add the jpeg pdf to each pdf in folder2

Comment: Your explanation is a bit confusing. I'm still not entirely sure what the situation is. It sounds like before you were saying both folders had 100 pdfs and now it sounds like you're saying that first folder has 1 file and second folder has 100.

Comment: If both folders have same amount of files another method comes to mind. You could use either a script or an application to rename the files separately. For example, Better Rename 9 has `Sequence Numbers` naming feature, which allows you to change the step value. With it, you could rename the files in the first folder to; `1, 3, 5, 7...` and files in the second folder to: `2, 4, 6, 8...`,  by changing the start number to 2. After that you'd just put the files in the same folder and use the Combine feature + the split feature in acrobat.

Comment: Hi mohad, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: @Joonas Thanks for the tip..I will try it out and keep you updated. To be more simple, Folder1 one has 100 image pdf (one page) and folder2 has 100 text pdf(many pages). So i need to combine each image with each pdf and store the combined output as a single pdf. (NOTE: each image pdf and text pdf is unique) BTW, the method you mentioned can be converted into actions right? because i want to automate this process and not do this manually for the 100 files.

Comment: Based on what you just said there, neither of my suggestions quite work. The first suggestion would work if the indd script would do all the work. A script would be pretty much as automatic as you want it to be. The trouble is that with something as specific as what you want, you'd have to code it yourself. I don't know if there is a better way or an alternative that doesn't require coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but your asking on wrong forum. Youd much more likely get a good answer on superuser than here. Merging PDF files isn't exactly a magic science.

Tools that would come handy:

- Acrobat DC Pro,as a gui tool for merging pdf files but then you'd have to run it 100 times. Can also be scripted to do this, but the scripting environment is a bit horrible (some info [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58339/replacing-non-consecutive-pages-from-one-indesign-exported-pdf-file-to-another/58445#58445)). I would make a demo but i havent got acrobat DC at home (yeah i arrived took me nearly the whole trip to craft the original message).
- PDF Fill
- PDF-Xchange, has a gui tool for merging pdf files but then you'd have to run it 100 times.
- Scripting language like python with pyPDF
- Indesign
- GhostScript
- [pdfunite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf)
- Batch scripting
- ...

Currently im writing this over on my phone and I'm a bit low on tools. So I'm going to show how to do this with python and pyPdf (because all I have on my phone is bash, tcsh, zsh and python. Aside the browser which implements javaScript).

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

for i in range(1,101):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    outputStream = file("output%d.pdf"%i, "wb")
    for item in [r"folder1\file%d.pdf"%i,r"folder2\file%d.pdf"%i]:
        fp = file(item,'rb')
        input = PdfFileReader(fp)
        output.addPage(input.getPage(0))
        output.write(outputStream)
        fp.close()
```

if you have got python but not pyPdf then run `pip install pyPdf` or `easy_install pyPdf` before running the script.

Comment: You could also mention [pdfsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/) as free platform independent option. Too bad that python syntax highlighting is not available here :)

Comment: @poor well python is paltform independent.  I did a quick count of applications that could do this with less than 20 lines of scripting on my work computer and i came up with a staggering count of 120 applications/tools that could do this.

Comment: AFAIK pdfsam is written in java, but does a solid job IMO.